# Custom query in Microsoft Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, office-2007

I am trying to make a custom query in access. I have a table where there are name of states.

For example: `Mexico, Texas, New York, Ohio, Indiana`

Now I want to show the details of all the Recruitment agency located in these states. I have that agency details in another table with states name.

When I will run the query then they will show me the states name and all the agency located there. I can do this part. The catch is that the states need to shown/sorted as I have written here. Means, the First one will be Mexico and all the agency that are located in Mexico.

The state name can come more then once if there are many agency. Next according to the serial the Texas will come and show the details.

For better understanding for how I want to show the result, here is the demo picture of what I am looking for.

[Demo Picture of how I want to show the database query](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9E6E00yDP09dlZJWllTQVQtVlk/view?usp=sharing)

This might be simple question with simple solution, but I can't find the right answer. I am new is Microsoft access. So please give me some idea or query or instruct me a complete way to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Add a number field (integer or long) to your states table and populate that with numbers in order of your desired sort. Then include that in your query and make the new field the first sort.
FYI, Mexico is not a state. It is a country.